# STATICFILES_DIR and STATIC_URL for modular templates

Tags: python, html, django

I am learning Django and trying to create modular templates and I am coming across this issue

In my Developer tools I am getting this error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/css/default.css          404 (NOT FOUND) 127.0.0.1/:8
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/assets/images/pythonlogo.jpeg   404 (NOT FOUND) 127.0.0.1/:84
```

From my understanding, having `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` allows {% static %} to be used and also appends `/static/` to the path of your static folder. Also, using `STATICFILES_DIR` is for locating the static files in your project.

Currently I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    ('assets', '/Users/BobDole/Development/django-brad/django_test/'),

)
```

From reading the documentation, it seems to me that `'assets'` is used as a namespace or a variable to represent `/Users/BobDole/Development/django-brad/django_test/`

In my html page I used

```
<img src="{% static 'assets/images/pythonlogo.jpeg' %}">  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'assets/css/default.css' %}">
```

My current project directory structure

```
django_test/
    admin/
    article/          <-- app
        templates/
    django_test/
        templates/
    images/
    static/
        css/
```

I believe that I am using STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIR improperly could some provide me with some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}assets/images/pythonlogo.jpeg">
```

Django will change STATIC_URL for /whatever/whatever/static/, so the url the img will access is: `/whatever/whatever/static/assets/images/pythonlogo.jpeg`

The thing is /whatever/whatever/static/ has to be the path until the "static" folder inclusive

I use in my projects STATIC_URL like this(**settings.py**):

```
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, "static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**EDIT** You have to add this 3 lines in your settings.py

Comment: I get a TemplateSyntaxError: invalid block tag: STATIC_URL

Comment: you have to define it in the settings.py

Comment: I've fight so many times with the urls in django, if you want we can chat in a room and I'll try to help you

Comment: I know... I'm not very good on chat xD I tried to invite you to a room called M.T.E...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41008/discussion-between-liondancer-and-liarez)

Answer (score 1):

What makes you think `assets` is magic in some way? It's not, it's simply the name of a directory. You don't have a directory called that, so you shouldn't use it. Use `{% static 'images/pythonlogo.jpeg' %}` etc.

Comment: I know I do not have a directory called assets but I thought it is a namespace for a directory path.